# ScrollViewer is unbounded while holding ItemsControl

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have a fairly complex application.  Many (prism) UserControls holding other UserControls etc...

Deep in one of the tabs of this application I have a UserControl (non prism) that has a Grid that is holding a ScrollViewer which in turn has a ItemsControl.

For some reason, the ScrollViewer is not bounded to the grid.  (I use snoop and it shows that the ScrollViewer is the full length of all the controls in the ItemsControl.)

This causes me to not get a scrollbar like I need.

Here is how it looks:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- Other stuff here -->

    <ScrollViewer   Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="3"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >

            <ItemsControl   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ExistingContainerTemplate}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding ExistingContainers}"
                            FocusVisualStyle="{DynamicResource InvisibleFocusVisualStyle}" Padding="2,0,0,0">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <local:ScrollIntoViewForItemsControl ScrollItem="{Binding ExistingContainerItem}" />
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The frustrating thing is that I try something similar in Kaxaml and it works just fine:

```
  <Grid>  
    <ScrollViewer Width="200" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5">
      <ItemsControl>
        <Rectangle Fill="Green" Width="100" Height="100"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="100" Height="100" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Black" Width="100" Height="100"/>
      </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
  </Grid>
```

If you have any idea how to get this bounded to the grid I would love to hear it.

Comment: there seems to be nothing wrong, I tried it and worked as expected. However I could not try with `ExistingContainerTemplate` `InvisibleFocusVisualStyle` and `ScrollIntoViewForItemsControl`, so cannot guarantee if any of then introduce the problem you face. So is it possible for you to post a working sample which shows the issue?

Comment: @pushpraj - I appreciate you looking into my issue.  I had tried what you suggested.  (I probably should have removed them from the code I posted.)  Turns out I had a grid higher up that had it in a row with size "auto".   Once I changed that to * it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I had a grid surrounding all of this that had a RowDefinition with a height of "Auto".

Because it was Auto, it was growing to fit all the content.

Once I switched that to * it worked fine.

Comment: Great find! happy coding :)